# longtabu and rotatebox resulting on too wide table

Tags: boxes, rotating, longtabu

I'm trying to produce a fixed full-width table, that can potentially span multiple pages. I found that rotating headers with `\rotatebox` messes up the dimension computation, but I can't find a way to work around it. `\makebox` for example gets ignored.

Test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{Xll}
some simple text & \rotatebox{90}{some really really really long text} & \rotatebox{90}{some really really really long text} \\
some simple text & \multicolumn{2}{l}{some much shorter text} \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The `\multicolumn` isn't ignored, it just doesn't take part in the width calculation. (Normally there are enough non spanning cells that that isn't a problem, but here it is).

It's easier to see if you put rules in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{|X|l|l|}
some simple text & \rotatebox{90}{some really really really long text} & 
\rotatebox{90}{some really really really long text} \\
some simple text & \multicolumn{2}{l}{some much shorter text} \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

so `X` gets all the space except for the space needed by the rotated headings, then the multicolumn is put in, and the table is too wide

```
Overfull \hbox (72.6446pt too wide) in alignment at lines 12--12
```

[image]

If there were some non spanning cells in the 2nd and 3rd columns they would have been seen earlier and the `X` column would have been given less space.

If there really are no such entries, you can add some, in a `\kill` row which is not typeset:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{|X|l|l|}
aaa&x\hspace{2.1cm}x&x\hspace{2.1cm}x\kill
some simple text & \rotatebox{90}{some really really really long text} &  
\rotatebox{90}{some really really really long text} \\
some simple text & \multicolumn{2}{l}{some much shorter text} \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This still doesn't work properly as the last two columns now have way too much space.

Comment: @joerg you can adjust the `\kill` row values to get different effects `aaa&x\hspace{1.3cm}x&x\hspace{1.3cm}x\kill` is about as tight as you can go I think (personally I never use `tabu`):-)

Comment: I ended up using a `\kill` row with manually computed width for the computation. The combination of `\settowidth` and `\dimexpr` works well for now. Of course, a better solution would be welcome :)